# Python - Common Improvements

Tags: discussion, repeated-reviews

What are the most common improvements of Python code you've applied or seen applied (to you or someone else) here on codereview?

Comment: It's not clear what you asking. Is this question meant for reviewers?

Comment: @Tshepang: Yes, but not them only :) I put that last "applied here on codereview" just to keep the answers focused and on topic. I'll update the question to made it more clear.

Comment: This question is also related to 2 others you have asked here on Meta ([first](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/474), [second](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/482)). Maybe you also wanna mention that fact?

Comment: @Tshepang: No I didn't wanted to mention that.

Comment: ...and why not?

Comment: @Tshepang: Because I didn't wanted to "scatter" the attention on why the question is there (your [first link](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/474/10415)), and at the [second link](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/482/10415) there seem to be nothing interesting: very little up/down vote partecipation, and the only upvoted answer it just tells to open this question.

Answer (score 6):

### Loops

In Python you should rarely use `while` loops or `for x in range(n)` loops. Python has a wide variety of tools like [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`itertools.*`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to iterate over pretty much anything with a `for` loop and an iterator.

Don't write:

```
for x in range(len(data)):
    print(data[x])
```

instead write:

```
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

Don't write:

```
for x in range(len(data)):
    print((x + 1, data[x]))
```

Write:

```
for index, item in enumerate(data, start=1):
    print((index, item))
```

Don't write:

```
for x in range(len(data1)):
    print(data1[x] + data2[x])
```

Write:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(data1, data2):
    print(item1 + item2)
```

(In Python 2, you'd use [`from future_builtins import zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html) to get the version of `zip` that returns an iterator instead of a list.)

Comment: It should be good to link to the doc, for `zip` etc.. And maybe it could also be added a warning at then to the py3k zip doc.

Comment: I'd love to see a concrete example.

Comment: In Python 2, the last example (with `zip`) allocates a list, which might not always be a good idea.

Comment: @GarethRees, feel free to edit of the answers on this page to improve them.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't yet have enough reputation on Code Review to edit answers.

Answer (score 5):

## file handling

Instead of closing files yourself, have the [`with statement`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) do it for you:

```
with open('filename') as filehandler:
    do_stuff(filehandler)
```

and not:

```
filehandler = open('filename')
do_stuff(filehandler)
filehandler.close()
```

Beyond saving you to have to close the file manually, the `with` statement also ensures the file will be closed even though exceptions rise during execution of `do_stuff()` function. That is, you get to avoid this ugliness:

```
filehandler = open('filename')
try:
    do_stuff(filehandler)
finally:
    filehandler.close()
```

Comment: I would apply this to more than just file handles. I use the with statement for StringIO and handling network connections as well. Anything that can be closed, and many things that can't are fair game. [contextlib.closing](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closingcontextlib.closing) for the win!

Answer (score 4):

Have as little code as possible in the global namespace. Most logic should be in functions, classes, or methods. This helps prevent polluting the global namespace and will run faster.

On a related note, the main function should look something like this:

```
def main(list_of_stuff):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

This is to avoid the globally-defined things, e.g. `sys.argv` in this case, to be executed should the module be called from another Python module. In our example, `main()` gets its `list_of_stuff` from the command line if ran directly, but if called from another module, that module must provide that list.

Answer (score 4):

### [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) -- Style Guide for Python Code

To follow a standard coding style is very important.

It's even more important if you want other people to look at your code.

By following the official coding style guide your code will be more readable and it will be way more easy for others programmers to understand it. You should really read [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it may seem long, but it's just a bunch of rules, the sooner you'll start to follow them, the better will be.

Anyway this is an attemp to summarize the most "overlooked" ones:

#### 1) [Indention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

Use 4 spaces per indentation level and never mix tabs and spaces.

#### 2) [Maximum Line Length](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. 80 is okey too.

#### 3) [Leave a space around the operators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

Yes:

```
i = 10
i = i + 1
i += 1
```

No:

```
i=10
i=i+1
i+=1
```

#### 4) [Documention strings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)

Conventions for writing good documentation strings (a.k.a. "docstrings") are immortalized in [**PEP 257**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), so take a look at that one too. Anyway in brief:

- [One-line Docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#one-line-docstrings): One-liners are for really obvious cases. They should really fit on one line. For example:

  def add(a, b):
      """Return a + b, for a and b numbers.."""
      return a + b
- [Multi-line Docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings): Multi-line docstrings consist of a summary line just like a one-line docstring, followed by a blank line, followed by a more elaborate description.

  The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable). Optional arguments should be indicated. It should be documented whether keyword arguments are part of the interface.

  Example:

  ```
  def fetch_bigtable_rows(big_table, keys, other_silly_variable=None):
      """Fetches rows from a Bigtable.

      Retrieves rows pertaining to the given keys from the Table instance
      represented by big_table.  Silly things may happen if
      other_silly_variable is not None.

      """
      # code starts from here
  ```

I don't want to make this section too complex, so other than [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) you can find more in the [google guidelines](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments), at [this example of pypi project](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example), and this SO question: [Docstrings - one line vs multiple line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392096/1132524).

**Note:** If a docstring become too complex to write/read/follow it's usually a sign that the function need to be refactored in two or more simple ones.

#### 5) [Naming Conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions)

You should read them all, anyway here's a small summary of the most common ones:

- "normal" variables and functions: `all_lowercase_with_underscore`.
   Dumb and verbose example:

  ```
  def my_function(first_arg, second_arg):
      sum_of_args = first_arg + second_arg
      # ...
  ```
- Class Names: `CamelCase`. Example:

  ```
  class MyClass:
      # ...
  ```
- Constants: `ALL_CAPS`.
  Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples:

  ```
  MAX_OVERFLOW = 100
  TOTAL = 70
  ```

Comment: I've started with PEP8 beacuse the lack of following this coding style guide happens very often and divert the attention from the "real" review.

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't dump the PEP-8 here, but instead cover specific issues it addresses in separate Answers.

Answer (score 2):

#### Naming:

- classes: `NameOfClass()`
- constants: `NAME_OF_CONSTANT`
- all else: `name_of_function()`, `name_of_variable`
- general: avoid abbreviations in names (e.g. `cnt` should be `counter`)

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
if (check):
    do_something()
```

This should be written as:

```
if check:
    do_something()
```

That is, you don't need to put stuff in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through my own reviews, I'd say that the two issues that come up almost every time are:

1. **Docstrings**. It feels as if nearly every review I have written has begun by noting the absence of user documentation in the poster's code. ([For example.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/15294/11728)) As a user I expect to be able to type `help(module)` or `help(module.function)` into the Python interpreter, and as a programmer I find that the discipline of specifying exactly what each function and class should do helps enormously to come up with good designs, good code structure, and good names.
2. **Doctests**. For some types of code these are a really simple way to combine example code with small test cases. Of course no-one should be fooled into thinking that they are a substitute for a proper test suite, but they are so easy to write that they deserve to be much more widely known and used. For example, [here's a question containing a bug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/15336/11728) that would have been easily caught by a simple doctest or two. [And here's another.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/15228/11728)

The third most common problem is probably inappropriate choice of data structures and algorithms (for example, [trying to write a parser without a lexer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/15395/11728)). But that's not really specific to Python.