# Posting very simple questions as exemplars

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, repeated-reviews

I noticed a couple things that have been pointed out repeatedly.  Having an exemplar of that single issue (not a bunch of issues in a long piece of code) can be pointed back to along with a simple note.  People elaborate on the issue to various degrees, but really there could be a comprehensive explanation **with references** to other resources and examples.

I’d like to run it by the group before posting one, and also ask that a tag be created for that purpose.  People can search for `[exemplar]` along with a language tag to find these (in particular, experienced answer writers can check the collection).

If there are naturally-occuring posts that have *one* clear issue, referring back to that is great.  But they should still be tagged so I can discover them and know they exist.

Candidates for exemplars:

### Don’s write `using namespace std;`

> **OP:**  waaaah, why not?
>   **OA:** adds a paragraph into the answer, which is kind of over-focused mini-lesson when the rest of the post just lists the problems briefly.
>   **another expert:** adds a comment with length limit and no para breaks that recaps his favorite reason.
>   **someone else:**  adds a comment giving a link to a detailed “why” post on SO or elsewhere, if he happens to take the trouble to look it up again.

### Don’t write naked `new` or `delete` anymore.

### Prefer non-member functions for `begin`, `end`, etc.

> Why is well beyond the scope of the question, but you should *learn* it the right way and you’ll be glad later.  Oh, and here’s the needed two-step way you need to do it.
>   Again, a detailed explanation here can run to several paragraphs and gets too deep and breaks the flow since this is not a single-issue answer.  Some things *need* single-issue answers to explain properly.

Comment: highly related: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1644/canonical-questions-to-help-address-common-issues